# Difference between $this->helper and Mage::helper

Tags: template, helper, blocks

Is the following codes in the  phtml `$this->helper('catalog/category')` and `Mage::helper('catalog/category')` returns the same object?

What is the meaning of using `$this->helper()` and `Mage::helper()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically the `$this->helper` is calling the function that is contained inside the current template's block class. The `Mage::helper` is calling the function in the "God" class.

The `$this->helper` normally calls a function in the class `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` which checks the layout for a helper and then simply calls the normal `Mage::helper` if it cannot find one.

```
/**
 * Returns helper object
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
 */
public function helper($name)
{
    if ($this->getLayout()) {
        return $this->getLayout()->helper($name);
    }
    return Mage::helper($name);
}
```